# post_date vs. post_modified - what's the difference?

Tags: posts

Recently I was surprised to find out that `post_date` and `post_modified` fields contain the same values. Isn't a `post_date` supposed to hold the creation date for the post? And shouldn't only `post_modified` change for all future updates? For now they all get changed simultaneously for every update.

Comment: Supposing that you are looking directly in the database, be sure you are looking the correct type of post: not revision, auto-draf, etc.

Comment: It is a custom post type and it has revisions disabled on it. I look it up in the database by the ID and it is the only one in the list.

Comment: Yes, what you expect to happen is what is supposed to happen. If the issue is not related to that mentioned by @cybnet, then something is modifying that behavior on your site. Disable your plugins and switch to a bundled theme. Do you still see this issue?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't occur on fresh installation.